# React Set State of Child Variable

Tags: reactjs

I have what I think is a very simple issue but I can't find what I am looking for through Googling and checking other threads on Stack Overflow.

I have the following code to set the value of my_var inside of the user as follows:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    prevState.user.my_var = 'myval';
        return prevState;
});
```

and this is called when a form field changes. However, I want to set the variable value when the page loads in componentDidMount() and although the above code works in this scenario I'm sure this isn't the correct syntax. I was expecting something like this to be the solution:

```
this.setState({
    user.my_var = cookies.get('dC')
});
```

But this doesn't work and it seems React doesn't like the child element being updated directly. What is the correct syntax for what I am trying to achieve?

The setup of user is as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: {
            my_var: ''
        },
    };
}
```

Thanks and apologies for the noob question.

Answer (score 0):

Updating a child element of this.state is not recommended in React. Instead, you should create a new object that includes the updated value and use that object to update the state:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { user } = this.state;
  const updatedUser = { ...user, my_var: "<whatever_you_want_to_put>" };
  this.setState({ user: updatedUser });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally in React you would not mutate the current state, but rather return a copy which has been modified. By doing `prevState.user.my_var = ...` you are mutating state.

Using your `prevState` method could be done like so:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
        ...prevState,
        user: {
            ...prevState.user, my_var: 'my_val'
        }
    }
});
```

Or without `prevState`:

```
this.setState({
    user: { ...this.state.user, my_var: cookies.get('dC') } 
});
```